# SELECT DISTINCT 2 columns in a INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a problem with a query for MySQL, i have to get rows with distinct "c.email" AND distinct "pf.cliente_id", I'm doing this code below, but i'm not getting what i want, the "c.email" don't returns DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.nome as nome, pf.id_cliente as cliente_id
FROM cliente c
INNER JOIN pessoa_fisica pf
ON c.id_cliente = pf.id_cliente
GROUP BY c.email, pf.id_cliente;
```

I Also tried:

```
SELECT c.nome as nome, pf.id_cliente as cliente_id
FROM cliente c
INNER JOIN pessoa_fisica pf
ON c.id_cliente = pf.id_cliente
GROUP BY c.email, pf.id_cliente;
```

**Edit**

cliente = email( It's not the primary key, is a foreign key and i have it reapeted )

pessoa_fisica = id_cliente ( It's not the primary key, is a foreign key and i have it reapeted )

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Your queries would appear to be the right queries, at least as I interpret the question.

Comment: This sounds like perhaps you dont understand the definition of `distinct`.  It means that the *group of items* will be unique to the collection.  so 1,2 is distinct from 1,3 even though you have 1 in both.  If you are looking for a list of unique email address and a list of unique client_id's, you might need 2 queries.  As gordon suggests, post sample data and expected results.

Comment: What you describe is almost assuredly impossible to obtain. Not because of any problem with SQL, but because it is a contradictory request. You can have a list of distinct ids and a list of distinct emails. But you can't have both as two fields in single rows. What happens when you have two distinct ids with the same email? You will have to filter out one of the rows. Now you're missing an id. Since you say both can be repeated, it seems it can be reversed: two emails and one name.

You can have distinct ids with whatever emails are associated, but you will get repeats. Or vice versa. Choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this query world work for you may be syntax error there because i have not database.

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(full, ' ', 1) AS email ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(full, ' ', -1) AS cliente_id , nome
from 
(SELECT DISTINCT (concat(c.email as email,' ',pf.id_cliente )) as 'full' , c.nome as 'nome'
FROM cliente c
INNER JOIN pessoa_fisica pf
ON c.id_cliente = pf.id_cliente) as temp;
```

Mysql distinct doesn't allow multiple values, but apply little effort means first concat columns and then apply distinct then break column again. I am setting an example for you.

```
   Create Table: CREATE TABLE `dupli` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `fname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `lname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

     insert into dupli (fname,lname) values ('Hitesh', 'mundra'),('Neeraj', 'sharma'),('Kailash','yadav');

     insert into dupli (fname,lname) values ('Hitesh', 'mundra'),('Neeraj', 'sharma'),('Kailash','yadav');

    select id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', 1) AS fname ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', -1) AS lname  from (select  distinct( concat(fname," ",lname) ) as Name, id from dupli) as temp;
```